# Is it possible to omit commands using GLI in Ruby for CLI?

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface, gli-gem

I wonder if it is possible to leave off commands and just use switches and flags using GLI?

For example `bundle exec bin/my_app show --info` can be done, but what about `bundle exec bin/my_app --info` ?

Thanks.

Comment: What would you expect to happen in such case?

Comment: To have actions as in `optparse`. what else..

Comment: Maybe just use `optparse` then?